# MS ACCESS Listbox shows number instead of characters

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I created a form using one of my query as a source, inside that form is a list box which is also used the same query as a source. My problem is some of the fields inside the list box display's the ID number instead of character even though in the query, names are display instead of the ID. Here's a little summary of how I connect my tables. I have Device_list table, and within this table I have multiple columns and two of those columns named Device_type and Employee_ID which is referenced to Employee_details table and Device_type table. When I generate a query table from the Device_list table the result appear as per my desired output.

I don't know how do I tweak it on my list box so that I can display the Device Type and my Employee ID field as character instead of ID number.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely source of confusion is that you have set up table fields that contain IDs to display their referenced string values instead. That carries over to the display of query results but not to list boxes or combo boxes.

On your list box source query make sure you are using the fields with the actual string values you expect to see and not the fields with the ID numbers.

Comment: `On your list box source query make sure you are using the fields with the actual string values you expect to see and not the fields with the ID numbers.` I'm not sure which source are you referring to, do you the CONTROL SOURCE?

Comment: The `RowSource` property.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use bound Combo Boxes instead of list boxes.  Try creating a query that shows all the fields you want to show in the combo box plus the field that needs to be bound.  You can use that query (or copy the SQL statement) as the ROW source for the combo box.  If you want the first field to be the bound field, but don't want to show it, set the Column Count to include that field, then set the Column Widths to start with zero.  For instance, if you want to display two fields that describe the data (maybe the second and third fields in the table), but bind the first field (maybe a number field), you would set the Column Count to 3 and set the Column Widths to something like this:  0;.5";1";).  Using a query as the row source allows you to filter, sort, etc.